# Cannot suppress warnings automatically in .Net Core Console project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

Steps to replicate on VS 2017 Enterprise:

- Create new .Net Core solution with a Console App project
- Add the following NuGet package:

  - Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers v2.3.0-beta1
- Run code analysis with the Error List filtered to "Build Only"
- You should see a CA1801 warnings for the unused "args" parameter of the Main method
- Right click on this in the errors list.

No "suppress" option is available.

Does anyone have any idea why the suppress warning isn't there?